# Is GLX_ARB_multisample supported by OSX

Tags: macos, opengl, glfw

I'm trying to use glfw3 with OpenGL 3.3 (core profile) on OSX with full screen anti-alisiang via `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES,4)`. My extension loader glad tells me that `GLX_ARB_multisample` is not supported, which is required for `GLFW_SAMPLES` to work.

My question is very basic: Am I doing something wrong or is multi-sampling currently not supported by glfw on OSX?

Comment: Well, the last few times I've built GLFW3, the test program: `tests/msaa.c` seemed to work fine. So the source is certainly worth looking at.

Comment: Thanks! That's encouraging...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `GLX_ARB_multisample` is not supported by OSX's native GL API.

> My extension loader glad tells me that `GLX_ARB_multisample` is not supported, which is required for `GLFW_SAMPLES` to work.

You are totally wrong here. `GLX_ARB_multisample` is an GLX extension, which is relevant for the X11 Window System, not for OSX's  Cocoa/`NSOpenGL` APIs. OSX does support multisampling, and it is controlled via the [`NSOpenGLPFASamples`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsopenglpfasamples) attribute, and GLFW is using it.

If you even try to load GLX extensions on that platform, you are doing something wrong (and this is not glad's fault).

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the explanation. Now I see that the part of the documentation where it talks about GLX extensions is only relevant to the X Window System (http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/compat_guide.html). Too many acronyms!

Comment: @genpfault: well, yes. That's why I wrote about the  "native" API, although I agree that this is debatable.